# Confusions About Arrays

Tags: c

I have multiple questions about arrays in C. This is my first time using and learning c and using ubuntu. Ignore the question mark in the beginning Its just a space filler for now.

Number one is correct.

Number Two if the value of `i` in the array is less than or equal to `7` then `i` multiply it by Euler constant by using `M_E` in `math.h` and if greater than `7` I convert it into absolute value. I am pretty sure I did this part correct if not feedback is appreciated.

Number three I have to convert all float points value in f_array into an `int` and put it into `i_array`. I use the round function to do this. I don't know if this was the right approach to it. I think i can remove the second increment `j` and just use `i` for both `f_array` and `i_array` but I'm not 100% sure

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        // Local variables
        // NOTE: this is where you will want to add some new variables
        float f_array[20];
        int i_array[20], m_array[25];
        ???

        // Step #1 - read in the float numbers to process
        for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
            scanf("%f", &f_array[i]);
        }

        // Step #2 - convert the input values
        for (i=0; i<20; i++){
            if (f_array[i] <= 7){
                i = i*M_E;
            }
            if (f_array[i] > 7){
                i = abs(i);
            }
        }


        // Step #3 - convert the floating point values to integers
        for (i=0; i<20; i++){
            for (j=0; j<20; j++){
                old = f_array[i]
                new = round(old)
                i_array[j] = new
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? The compiler will already give you a few hints about errors in the code. Looking at the result should give you a few more.

Comment: In step 2 you're changing your loop variable in the body of the loop, which is uncommon and usually not intended.  And `i = abs(i)` can't be right, since it suggests `i` might be negative, in which case you already would have indexed outside of your array bounds.  So yeah, step 2 is seriously broken.

Answer (score 0):

In `Step 2`, you're not `converting input values`, you're just using them in `if conditions`, then you're "multiplying" your `loop counter(i)`  OR "converting it to absolute" instead of your actual stored values in `f_array`.

Then again, you're storing the value **IN THE LOOP COUNTER**, which in other words, "You're discarding the converted values".

You're second loop should look like this

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++){
    if (f_array[i] <= 7){
       m_array[i] = f_array[i]*M_E; //I suppose that was m_array was supposed to store
    }
    else if (f_array[i] > 7){
       m_array[i] = abs(f_array[i]);
    }
}
```

And **YES** you can remove the second increment from third `for`. It should look like

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++){
   i_array[i] = round(f_array[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you I changed the m_array to f_array because m_array is used for another problem.